# Load different xib

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xib

In my app I've to load 2 different .xib: one to support the retina 3.5 display of iPhone 4/4s and one to supporto retina 4 display of iPhone 5/5c/5s.
I made this so:
first I defined a constant in this way:

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

and I made this method to load the different xib files:

```
- (IBAction)callViewController:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
        ScannerViewController *scannerVC = [[ScannerViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ScannerViewControllerRetina4" bundle:nil];
        [scannerVC setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
        [self presentViewController:scannerVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        ScannerViewController *scannerVC = [[ScannerViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ScannerViewController" bundle:nil];
        [scannerVC setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
        [self presentViewController:scannerVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

I created 2 xib: ScannerViewController and ScannerViewControllerRetina4. When I run the app on the simulator with retina 3.5 it works, but when I run the app with retina 4 it says: `loaded the "ScannerViewControllerRetina4" nib but the view outlet was not set.` I associated the 2 xib File's Owner to the class `ScannerViewController`
What's wrong on my code? How I can fix it?

Comment: Didi connect the outlet of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just connect your `UIViewController` outlet's to your main view. You can do that by control dragging from the ScannerViewControllerRetina4 to your main view.